# No similar answers found. Crawling or scraping the website that is made by Angular.js by using Node.js or other way

Tags: angularjs, node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler

No similar answers found.

I am writing this message because I want to be able to solve the problems raised in the development process.
I tried to scrape an Angular website by using nodejs, but I can't get any specific information.
Place some of the scraped information below

```html
<section ng-if="toShow === 1" class="video-content race--overlay pre--race">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="r in nextRunners | orderBy:'card_number'" class="pre__runner slide-animation">
            <header class="pre__runner--header" ng-class="{'rider--name':r.rider_name!=''}">
                <div class="video__item pre__runner--icon pre__section">
                    <category-icon category="iconWithNumber"
                                   class="jockey--silks"
                                   sport="sport_id+1"
                                   colour="r.card_number">
                    </category-icon>
                </div>
                <div class="video__item pre__runner--info pre__section"
                     ng-class="{'has--jockey':r.rider_name !== ''}">
                    <h2 class="pre__runner--name">{{r.participant_name}}</h2>
                    <h3 ng-if="r.rider_name!==''" class="pre__runner--jockey">{{r.rider_name}}</h3>
                </div>
            </header>
            <section class="pre__runner--history pre__section">
                <dl class="video__item">
                    <dt>{{::raceLang.last5}}:</dt>
                    <dd>{{r.last_five}}</dd>
                </dl>
            </section>
            <section class="pre__runner--odds pre__section">
                <h3 class="video__item">{{::raceLang.odds}}: <span>{{r.oddsWin}}</span></h3>
            </section>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

As you can see from the code, all the data that you need to get is hidden.

For example: `{{::raceLang.last5}}, {{r.last_five}}`

Is there no way to solve this?
Please help.

Comment: Is that the source? or the contents of the Elements panel?

Comment: yeah, over code is contents of the Elements panel.

Comment: i have no source code of angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular is a framework to build Single Page Application. Tipically, theese kind of web applications are rendered client side, thanks to the Javascript's execution by the browser.
When you fetch a page from a well done Single Page Application, you are actually always fetching index.html or, if you hack a bit, some other incomplete html source file.

There are several solutions:

### **Pre-Render pages**

if you have control over the webserver you are fetching data from, you could pre-render your pages. This will require a knowlege of the build process and even of the enviorment configuration. This is probably an over-complicated solution for your needs.

### Browser emulation

For a simpler approach or if you do not have control of the server you are fetching data from, you have to simulate a Browser. Take a look at [zombie](http://zombie.js.org/). [Phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/) works good, but the project is no longer mantained.

### Use application API

You could inspect the application using your favorite browser. Angular application tipically rely on APIs. If you understand wich API call the application is doing, you could probably get all data you need in a nice format (JSON tipically), without need of performing any boring html parsing. Sometimes, depending on server security policies, you have to properly setup some HTTP Headers to act like a Browser or an authenticathed user.

Comment: thank for your answer. i have interest in "Use application API". but i dont know well about it. can you help me?

Comment: it means ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using the application API. I called AJAX and got the JSON data and it worked very well. Although I had to add some HTTP headers...